# C# - ActiveMQ - Task in Consumer

Tags: c#, .net, activemq-classic

Suppose we have a queue in ActiveMQ, a client that sends messages (producer) to that queue and a server that gets the messages (consumer) from the queue.

On the server side the consumer has a message listener, something like:

```
consumer.Listener += ConsumerOnListener;
```

and the implementation of  ConsumerOnListener looks like the following:

```
private void ConsumerOnListener(IMessage message)
{
     var textMessage = message as ITextMessage;
     // validate textMessage

     // more code here...eg. save to databse,logging etc. (part-a)

     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     { 
         // do something else here (part-b)
     });
}
```

The main idea behind the above is not to wait for **part-b** to be executed before processing the next message. Imagine that **part-b** does something completely of its own which may be succeeded or not(fire-and-forget).

So, the question here is whether is OK or not to use Tasks inside ConsumerOnListener. Will this somehow 
"block" the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `Task` is asynchronous then it shouldn't block either the execution of the listener or the queue itself. Typically concurrency in use-cases like this is increased by simply increasing the number of consumers/listeners, but it's also valid to have listeners kick off their own async threads, tasks, etc.